# Why Math.atan() and Math.atan2() are returning different results?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, atan2, atan

I have the below function returning me angles in radians from three points coded as below:

```
function pointsToAngles(x1, y1, x2, y2, cpx, cpy) {
    const r1 = Math.atan((y1 - cpy)/(x1 - cpx));
    const r2 = Math.atan((y2 - cpy)/(x2 - cpx));

    return [r1, r2];
}
```

I understand that `atan()` as it supposed to returns results in the `-pi/2` to `pi/2` range, so JavaScript provides `atan2()` returning `-pi` to `pi` range. I would like to rewrite function to use atan2, probably as:

```
function pointsToAngles(x1, y1, x2, y2, cpx, cpy) {
    const r1 = Math.atan2((x1 - cpx), (y1 - cpy));
    const r2 = Math.atan2((x2 - cpx), (y2 - cpy));

    return [r1, r2];
}
```

However, the `atan2` version is not working as expected. I get different results than the `atan()` produces and it does not follow the logic what I would expect to follow [with difference being pi/2 or something...].

It appears that `atan()` version is working correctly, and `atan2()` version is not. What am I missing? How would I calculate angles in a way similar to atan() only returning angles over pi/2 large?

Comment: What does “working correctly” mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have swapped the arguments of the Math.atan2() function. The correct order of the arguments should be **(y, x)**, not **(x, y)** [Math.atan2()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2).